# Why doesn't HttpRequest.getSession(true) get new session when old one null/invalid

Tags: session, websphere, httprequest

Can anybody explain, when I run this java code:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null)
    {
            s_log.debug("Session has id: " + session.getId());
            session.invalidate();
    }
    s_log.debug("Request Session ID is: "+  request.getRequestedSessionId()); 
    s_log.debug("Request isRequestedSessionIdValid(): " + request.isRequestedSessionIdValid());
    HttpSession _session = request.getSession(true);
     s_log.debug("New Session is :" + _session.getId());
```

Why I don't get a new session from the request.getSession(true) when the current request session is null and is invalid?  I see this in the log:

Request Session ID is: 0000MYF8m5fpUjrzUHIp93yshSh:5e7fcdcf-2274-43bb-83d9-4d9b9a1d766a

Request isRequestedSessionIdValid(): false

New Session is :MYF8m5fpUjrzUHIp93yshSh

Comment: Also, when I run the application via Eclipse running Websphere App Server in debug mode, it gets a new session as expected.  However, when I run outside of eclipse with Websphere in non-debug mode, it does not get a new session.

Answer (score 0):

It's the session ID that is being reused. The actual session is being invalidated and recreated.

This behaviour can be changed by setting [HttpSessionIdReuse](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rprs_custom_properties.html?view=kc#HttpSessionIdReuse) property value to false.

Comment: I tried that by setting server.xml to have <httpSession cookieSecure="false" cookieHttpOnly="true" reuseSessionID="false"/> but it still reuses the session id.  I also tried using <httpSessionDatabase dataSourceRef="ccprod" useInvalidatedId="false" /> and that didn't work either.